# MySQL exclude NULL / empty match?

Tags: mysql

I've got this statement:

```
SELECT id FROM laptops
WHERE (hostname = :hostname)
OR (asset_tag = :asset_tag)
OR (serial = :serial) LIMIT 1
```

Essentially I want to check there isn't a match on any of those three fields. The problem is, I'm getting matches where there shouldn't be, which leads me to think that if one of those fields is empty in both MySQL and the data being checked, it flags as a match. Does that sound correct? If so, how I can exclude empty values from this matching process?

Comment: By empty, do you mean `NULL` or an empty string?  A `NULL` value would fail the comparisons, so nothing would be returned.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I'm comparing against empty strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, pretty straightforward answer as it turns out:

```
SELECT id FROM laptops
WHERE (hostname = :hostname && hostname != '')
OR (asset_tag = :asset_tag && asset_tag !='')
OR (serial = :serial && serial != '') LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon: I think he is looking for

```
SELECT id FROM laptops
WHERE (hostname != :hostname)
AND (asset_tag != :asset_tag)
AND (serial != :serial) LIMIT 1
```